# Get element by href in jquery not working?

Tags: jquery, href

I want to add class (d_select) to a tag which href is "#tut" by click at Show.

But When i click, nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
 <a class="show"><span>Show!</span></a>       

            <ul class="tab_cm">
                <li><a href="#details">Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="#feed">Feedback</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tut">Tutorial</a></li>
                <li><a href="#map">Map</a></li>
            </ul>

<script>
$(function(){
    $(".show").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("ul.tab_cm").find('a[href="#tut"]').addClass("d_select");
    });
});
</script>
```

***I speak English not well, i'm so sorry!***

Comment: your code works fine here :  http://jsfiddle.net/48aee/ Perhaps your css  rule for the class isn't specific enough

Comment: I tested the code as well, it is the right code, but your class is probably being overridden by a:link css rule.  Use F12 in Google Chrome, find the element, and then look at CSS class rules to see which one is taking precedence over D-select.

Comment: I make something wrong at my class name!
Big thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try `$("ul.tab_cm").find('a[href="\\#tut"]').addClass("d_select");`

`\\` will escape a character that has special CSS meaning when used as part of a selector... although it seems JQuery is smart enough to know the `#` in an attribute reference is a literal anyway, so this shouldn't be required.

Comment: @Boulevard Maybe make an answer showing what you did and how you changed it to help others who do the same thing.

Comment: @Plynx no need to escape the `#` when in quotes